# Validate form field only on submit or user input

Tags: angularjs

I have form fields that are validated using `required`. The problem is, that the error is displayed immediately when the form is rendered. I want it only to be displayed after the user actually typed in the text field, or on submit.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use `$dirty` flag to show the error only after user interacted with the input:

```html
<div>
  <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required />
  <span ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.required">Email is required</span>
</div>
```

If you want to trigger the errors only after the user has submitted the form than you may use a separate flag variable as in:

```html
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="form" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required />
    <span ng-show="(form.email.$dirty || submitted) && form.email.$error.required">
      Email is required
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope){
  $scope.submit = function(){
    // Set the 'submitted' flag to true
    $scope.submitted = true;
    // Send the form to server
    // $http.post ...
  } 
};
```

Then, if all that JS inside `ng-show`expression looks too much for you, you can abstract it into a separate method:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope){
  $scope.submit = function(){
    // Set the 'submitted' flag to true
    $scope.submitted = true;
    // Send the form to server
    // $http.post ...
  }

  $scope.hasError = function(field, validation){
    if(validation){
      return ($scope.form[field].$dirty && $scope.form[field].$error[validation]) || ($scope.submitted && $scope.form[field].$error[validation]);
    }
    return ($scope.form[field].$dirty && $scope.form[field].$invalid) || ($scope.submitted && $scope.form[field].$invalid);
  };

};
```

```html
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="form">
  <div>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required />
    <span ng-show="hasError('email', 'required')">required</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just starting out with Angular and the abstraction to a "hasError" method is really nice thanks!

Comment: the hasError function do not appear to work using angular 1.2. it doesn't look like the controller has access to the form.

Comment: @SethM. Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: @SethM. That `hasError` method expects the form name to be `form`, not `myForm`.

Comment: Ok, i changed all instances of "form" to be "myForm" and it seems to work. You example has the names mixed.

Comment: Isn't that bad to refer form elements in the controller?

Comment: Well, my simplified examples implicitly rely on $scope.form, but you could as well pass the form instance directly to the `hasError` method: `$scope.hasError = function(form, field, validation){...`, `ng-show="hasError(form, 'email', 'required')"`. Futhermore, you may move the `hasError` function into a separate service, so that you may use it in any controller without repeating yourself.

Comment: Instead of $scope.submitted you could check 'ng-submitted' class on form

Comment: To get this to work with a newer version of AngularJS, I had to use `$scope.form.$submitted` instead of `$scope.submitted`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to show error messages on form submission, you can use condition `form.$submitted` to check if an attempt was made to submit the form. Check following example.

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="myForm.$valid && createUser()">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Enter name of user" required>
  <div ng-messages="myForm.name.$error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted">
    <div ng-message="required">Please enter user name.</div>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="user.address" placeholder="Enter Address" required ng-maxlength="30">
  <div ng-messages="myForm.name.$error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted">
    <div ng-message="required">Please enter user address.</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Should be less than 30 chars</div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">
    Create user
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use angularjs form state `form.$submitted`. 
Initially `form.$submitted` value will be `false` and will became `true` after successful form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Erik Aigner,

Please use $dirty(The field has been modified) and $invalid (The field content is not valid).

Please check below examples for angular form validation

1)

Validation example HTML for user enter inputs:

```
<form  ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
  <p>Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
      <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
      <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
      </span>
  </p>
    </form>
```

2)

Validation example HTML/Js for user submits :

```
      <form  ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate form-submit-validation="">
      <p>Email:<br>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
        <span ng-show="submitted || myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
          <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
          <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
          </span>
      </p>
<p>
  <input type="submit">
</p>
</form>
```

Custom Directive :

```
app.directive('formSubmitValidation', function () {

        return {
            require: 'form',
            compile: function (tElem, tAttr) {

                tElem.data('augmented', true);

                return function (scope, elem, attr, form) {
                    elem.on('submit', function ($event) {
                        scope.$broadcast('form:submit', form);

                        if (!form.$valid) {
                            $event.preventDefault();
                        }
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.submitted = true;
                        });


                    });
                }
            }
        };


  })
```

3)

you don't want use directive use ng-change function like below

```
  <form  ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate ng-change="submitFun()">
      <p>Email:<br>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
        <span ng-show="submitted || myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
          <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
          <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
          </span>
      </p>
<p>
  <input type="submit">
</p>
</form>
```

Controller SubmitFun() JS:

```
 var app = angular.module('example', []);
 app.controller('exampleCntl', function($scope) {
 $scope.submitFun = function($event) {
 $scope.submitted = true;
  if (!$scope.myForm.$valid) 
  {
        $event.preventDefault();
   }
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Invoking of validation on form element could be handled by triggering change event on this element:

a) exemple: trigger change on separated element in form

```
$scope.formName.elementName.$$element.change();
```

b) exemple: trigger change event for each of form elements for example on ng-submit, ng-click, ng-blur ...

```
vm.triggerChangeForFormElements = function() {
    // trigger change event for each of form elements
    angular.forEach($scope.formName, function (element, name) {
        if (!name.startsWith('$')) {
            element.$$element.change();
        }
    });
};
```

c) and one more way for that

```
    var handdleChange = function(form){
        var formFields = angular.element(form)[0].$$controls;
        angular.forEach(formFields, function(field){
            field.$$element.change();
        });
    };
```