# Automatically update untouched fields in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using form validation in angularjs, but I'm having the same problem as in this Google Groups-thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/W1Yya5TfIWo/7jZbfL-wROUJ, empty forms are "shouting" at users before they input values.

To solve this, I only show the error messages if the fields are `$dirty` (has been touched by the user). However, if the user directly submits the form without touching anything, the form will not be submitted (as it is not `$valid`) but it will not show any error messages either (becuase the fields aren´t `$dirty`).

It is then suggested in the previously linked Google Groups-thread to "touch" the fields on invalid form submit. I do this using something like below:

```
$scope._updateUntouchedFields = function(form) {
  for(var f in form) {
    var field = form[f];

    if (field.$addControl !== undefined) {
      // $addControl exists, this is a nested form
      // recursively update fields in that form
      $scope._updateUntouchedFields(field);
    } else if (field.$setViewValue !== undefined) {
      // $setViewValue exists, this is a field, just
      // set the view value to the current view value
      if(field.$dirty) continue;
      field.$setViewValue(field.$viewValue);
    }
  }
};
```

The above function is callid if the form is invalid on submit. I have two problems with this:

1. How I determine if the current form control is a nested form seems a bit like a hack. Is there a better, more angular-like way? Ideally I would like a list of all form controls, no matter if they are nested in other forms or not.
2. Can this be done automatically somehow? Is there a way to override the form directive, or perhaps add a directive to the `<form>` tag where I could put this functionality? As it is now, I need to have it in every controller where I have a form, and add the logic to the submit function.

Comment: This might help you: [Validate form field only on submit or user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input/17452805#17452805)

Comment: Thanks, it's the same problem, but that introduces a local variable which is manually set at submit instead of using the $dirty state. I'm not sure which is best (both works), but I would still like to have this handled automatically somehow.