# AngularJS form validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have simple form:

```
<form  class="form-horizontal" name="loginForm" novalidate ng-click="login()" >
```

and inputs inside with "required":

```
<input required class="input-xlarge" ng-model="uEmail" placeholder="Email" type="email">
```

When user load the form always show error on startup.
How to start validation after user interaction?

Comment: Angular JS form validation : http://dailyjs.com/2013/06/06/angularjs-7/

However, i fiddled your mark up and ran it , found no errors . Here's  the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hgGfV/

Comment: I think this answers your question: "[Validate form field only on submit or user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input/17452805#17452805)"

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
<span ng-if="form.inputNmae.$touched && form.inputNmae.$error.required">Required input</span>
```