# show validation error messages on submit in angularjs

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I have a form which need to show validation error messages if clicked submit.

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nYPzEO8d3SKuFk4KBn1o?p=preview)

```
 <form name="frmRegister" ng-submit="register();" novalidate>
      <div>
        <input placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" required />
        <span ng-show="frmRegister.first_name.$dirty && frmRegister.first_name.$error.required">First Name is required</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" type="text" ng-model="user.lastName" required />
        <span ng-show="frmRegister.last_name.$dirty && frmRegister.last_name.$error.required">Last Name is required</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" required />
        <span ng-show="frmRegister.email.$dirty && frmRegister.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
        <span ng-show="frmRegister.email.$dirty && frmRegister.email.$error.email">Invalid Email address.</span>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      <span ng-show="registered">YOU ARE NOW REGISTERED USER</span>
 </form>
```

Validation works normally when user start making changes. But it doesn't show any error messages If clicked submit without entering anything.

Any thought of achieving this?. Or in other way how can I make each input field $dirty when clicks the Submit button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate form field only on submit or user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/ANxmv/2/ which does a nifty trick to cause control validation.

Basically it declares a scope member `submitted` and sets it true when you click submit. The model error binding use this extra expression to show the error message like

```
submitted && form.email.$error.required
```

---

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in [@Hafez's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798375/show-validation-error-messages-on-submit-in-angularjs#comment44380864_18799099) (give him some upvotes!), the [Angular 1.3+ solution](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state) is simply:

```
form.$submitted && form.email.$error.required
```

Comment: Just use `form.$submitted` according to documention https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state

Comment: Yes this solution is not reverent, post Angular 1.3. There is now a $submitted  property.

Comment: @Chandermani Just wanted to say that please include novalidate in ur working plunker. :)

Comment: @Chandermani: can you please help me with this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557554/issues-in-show-error-status-in-javascript

Comment: the solution works but I think that for a normal use case, it doesn't fill the requirement, the error should show up also for form.email.$touched && form.email.$error.required, so the best way to achieve the result is to leave the validation to the controller method, check for form validation then call $setTouched for every property.

Answer (score 13):

Since I'm using Bootstrap 3, I use a directive:
(see [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ED8x3?p=preview))

```
    var ValidSubmit = ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                return {
                    post: function postLink(scope, element, iAttrs, controller) {
                        var form = element.controller('form');
                        form.$submitted = false;
                        var fn = $parse(iAttrs.validSubmit);
                        element.on('submit', function(event) {
                            scope.$apply(function() {
                                element.addClass('ng-submitted');
                                form.$submitted = true;
                                if(form.$valid) {
                                    fn(scope, {$event:event});
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        scope.$watch(function() { return form.$valid}, function(isValid) {
                            if(form.$submitted == false) return;
                            if(isValid) {
                                element.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                            } else {
                                element.removeClass('has-success');
                                element.addClass('has-error');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]

    app.directive('validSubmit', ValidSubmit);
```

and then in my HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form" novalidate valid-submit="connect()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-1">
      <span class="input-group-addon input-large"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
      <input class="input-large form-control" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-model="email" required="required">
    </div>
    <p class="col-sm-offset-3 help-block error" ng-show="form.$submitted && form.email.$error.required">please enter your email</p>
    <p class="col-sm-offset-3 help-block error" ng-show="form.$submitted && form.email.$error.email">please enter a valid email</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

**UPDATED**

In my latest project, I use ***Ionic*** so I have the following, which automatically puts `.valid` or `.invalid` on the `input-item`'s:

```
.directive('input', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  function findParent(element, selector) {
    selector = selector || 'item';
    var parent = element.parent();
    while (parent && parent.length) {
      parent = angular.element(parent);
      if (parent.hasClass(selector)) {
        break;
      }
      parent = parent && parent.parent && parent.parent();
    }
    return parent;
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: ['?^ngModel', '^form'],
    priority: 1,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];
      var form = ctrls[1];

      if (!ngModelCtrl || form.$name !== 'form' || attrs.type === 'radio' || attrs.type === 'checkbox') {
        return;
      }

      function setValidClass() {
        var parent = findParent(element);
        if (parent && parent.toggleClass) {
          parent.addClass('validated');
          parent.toggleClass('valid', ngModelCtrl.$valid && (ngModelCtrl.$dirty || form.$submitted));
          parent.toggleClass('invalid', ngModelCtrl.$invalid && (ngModelCtrl.$dirty || form.$submitted));
          $timeout(angular.noop);
        }
      }

      scope.$watch(function () {
        return form.$submitted;
      }, function (b, a) {
        setValidClass();
      });


      var before = void 0;
      var update = function () {
        before = element.val().trim();
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(before);
        ngModelCtrl.$render();
        setValidClass();
      };
      element
        .on('focus', function (e) {
          if (ngModelCtrl.$pristine) {
            element.removeClass('$blurred');
          }

        })
        .on('blur', function (e) {
          if (ngModelCtrl.$dirty) {
            setValidClass();
            element.addClass('$blurred');
          }
        }).on('change', function (e) {
          if (form.$submitted || element.hasClass('$blurred')) {
            setValidClass();
          }
        }).on('paste', function (e) {
          if (form.$submitted || element.hasClass('$blurred')) {
            setValidClass();
          }
        })
      ;

    }
  };
}])
```

and then in the HTML:

```
    <form name='form' novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="auth.signin(form, vm)">
          <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="vm.email" autofocus="true" required
              >
          </label>
          <button ng-if="!posting" type="submit" class="item button-block item-balanced item-icon-right  call-to-action">Login<i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
          </button>
```

and in the controller:

```
  self.signin = function (form, data) {
    if (!form.$valid) return;

    Authentication.emailLogin(data)
    //...
```

so, now, in the CSS, you can do stuff like:

```
.item.valid::before{
    float: right;
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #66cc33;
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-size: 24px;
    content: "\f122";
}

.item.invalid::before{
    float: right;
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #ef4e3a;
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-size: 24px;
    content: "\f12a";

/*
    border-left: solid 2px #ef4e3a !important;
    border-right: solid 2px #ef4e3a !important;
*/
}
```

**MUCH SIMPLER!**

Comment: Very nice! I refined it a bit and provided the example with a Bootstrap 3 flavor in this [jsfiddl](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/LRD5x/2/)

Comment: Modified slightly to *require* the form controller. Now you can only combine the validSubmit directive on a `<form>` and you don't have to manually get the controller from the scope anymore. [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/LRD5x/3/).

Comment: And one more update that now includes autofocus on first input (and some comments): [new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/FeS4A/2/).

Comment: Might as well put a final version here: [final jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/FeS4A/4/).

Comment: what if i want to put `valid-submit` on my submit button? because i have other directives that work only on `submit` button

Comment: Should still work, I'd have to hear more about your use case. The submit button is always inside a form, so it should be easy to rewrite it and require the formController. There is not always a submit button though...

Comment: @malix  Can you explain this directive. From where it is called ? and what it is doing ?

Comment: @Plantface I combined your directive with another one which loops through all the form-group divs and watches the inputs so it can sets their has-error class when the validation state changes. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/97efc4f2f12ba51c5cf3

Comment: @Vadapalli It show validation errors, see the plunkr and the <form /> code above...

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue, I solved the problem by adding a ng-submit which sets the variable submitted to true.

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submitted = true" novalidate>
<div>
    <span ng-if="submitted && form.email.$error.email">invalid email address</span> 
    <span ng-if="submitted && form.email.$error.required">required</span>
    <label>email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
</div>

<div>
    <span ng-if="submitted && form.name.$error.required">required</span>
    <label>name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required>
</div>

<button ng-click="form.$valid && save(user)">Save</button>
</form>
```

I like the idea of using $submitted, I think I've to upgrade Angular to 1.3 ;)

Answer (score 4):

I can come up with 2 ways to achieve it.

The first one is to remove `novalidate` to enable the browser's validation.

Second, you can disable the `save` button when the form is not valid like this

```
<input ng-disabled="!frmRegister.$valid" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Removing novalidate give trouble in safari ios browser. It doesn't give validation popups. Also it feels little ambiguous for me(user) if  submit button disabled initially. But that's a nice way to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two simple & elegant ways to do it.

Pure CSS:

After first form submission, despite the form validity, Angular will add a `ng-submitted` class to all form elements inside the form just submitted.

We can use `.ng-submitted` to controller our element via CSS.

if you want to display an error text only when user have submitted e.g.

```
.error { display: none }
.ng-submitted .error {
     display: block;
}
```

Using a value from Scope:
After first form submission, despite the form validity, Angular will set `[your form name].$submitted` to true. Thus, we can use that value to control elements.

```
<div ng-show="yourFormName.$submitted">error message</div>
<form name="yourFormName"></form>
```

Comment: Yeah, you can do this now in 1.3+, but when OP asked 1.3 wasn't officially released :P

Answer (score 2):

My solution with bootstrap 3

http://jsfiddle.net/rimian/epxrbzn9/

```
<form class="form" name="form" ng-app novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="first_name"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          ng-model="first_name"
          placeholder="First Name"
          required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="last_name"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          ng-model="last_name"
          placeholder="Last Name"
          required />
  </div>

  <button
    type="submit"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
    ng-click="submitted=true">
      Submit
  </button>

<div ng-show="submitted && form.$invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
  <div ng-show="form.first_name.$error.required">
    First Name is Required
  </div>
  <div ng-show="form.last_name.$error.required">
    Last Name is Required
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: This change to the jsfiddle ng-show="(submitted && form.last_name.$invalid) || (!form.last_name.$pristine && form.last_name.$invalid)" will allow you to: 1. Hide validation when the form loads, 2. when form is submitted show all broken validation, 3. show validation message when the field has been touched.

Comment: @chrisghardwick Could please update the fiddle wit h your suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to check if the form is dirty and valid before submitting it. Checkout the following code.

```
<form name="frmRegister" data-ng-submit="frmRegister.$valid && frmRegister.$dirty ? register() : return false;" novalidate>
```

And also you can disable your submit button with the following change:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" data-ng-disable="frmRegister.$invalid || !frmRegister.$dirty" />
```

This should help for your initial

Comment: You could also use frmRegister.$pristine instead of !frmRegister.$dirty

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LRD5x/30/  A simple solution.

HTML

```html
<form ng-submit="sendForm($event)" ng-class={submitted:submitted}>
```

JS

```js
$scope.sendForm = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault()
  $scope.submitted = true
};
```

CSS

```
.submitted input.ng-invalid:not(:focus) {
    background-color: #FA787E;
}

input.ng-invalid ~ .alert{
    display:none;
}
.submitted input.ng-invalid ~ .alert{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution from [realcrowd](http://code.realcrowd.com/on-the-bleeding-edge-advanced-angularjs-form-validation/) the best.

HTML:

```
<form role="form" id="form" name="form" autocomplete="off" novalidate rc-submit="signup()">
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':  rc.form.hasError(form.firstName)}">
    <label for="firstName">Your First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name" ng-maxlength="40" required="required" ng-model="owner.name.first"/>
    <div class="help-block" ng-show="rc.form.hasError(form.firstName)">{{rc.form.getErrMsg(form.firstName)}}</div>
</div>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
//define custom submit directive
var rcSubmitDirective = {
'rcSubmit': ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['rcSubmit', '?form'],
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            this.attempted = false;

            var formController = null;

            this.setAttempted = function() {
                this.attempted = true;
            };

            this.setFormController = function(controller) {
              formController = controller;
            };

            this.hasError = function (fieldModelController) {
                if (!formController) return false;

                if (fieldModelController) {
                    return fieldModelController.$invalid && this.attempted;
                } else {
                    return formController && formController.$invalid && this.attempted;
                }
            };
            this.getErrMsg=function(ctrl){
                var e=ctrl.$error;
                var errMsg;
                if (e.required){
                    errMsg='Please enter a value';
                }
                return errMsg;
            }
        }],
        compile: function(cElement, cAttributes, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function(scope, formElement, attributes, controllers) {

                    var submitController = controllers[0];
                    var formController = (controllers.length > 1) ? controllers[1] : null;

                    submitController.setFormController(formController);

                    scope.rc = scope.rc || {};
                    scope.rc[attributes.name] = submitController;
                },
                post: function(scope, formElement, attributes, controllers) {

                    var submitController = controllers[0];
                    var formController = (controllers.length > 1) ? controllers[1] : null;
                    var fn = $parse(attributes.rcSubmit);

                    formElement.bind('submit', function (event) {
                        submitController.setAttempted();
                        if (!scope.$$phase) scope.$apply();

                        if (!formController.$valid) return false;

                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            fn(scope, {$event:event});
                        });
                    });
                }
          };
        }
    };
}]
};
app.directive(rcSubmitDirective);
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution to the validate form with angularjs.
HTML is as follows.

```
<div ng-app="areaApp" ng-controller="addCtrler">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="fareainfo">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="input-areaname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Area Name : </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="input-areaname" ng-model="Area.Name" placeholder="" required>
                      <span class="text-danger" ng-show="(fareainfo.$submitted || fareainfo.name.$dirty) && fareainfo.name.$error.required"> Field is required</span>
                  </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="submitAreaInfo()">Submit</button>
             </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

AngularJS App and Controller is as follows

```
var areaApp = angular.module('areaApp', []); 
areaApp.controller('addCtrler', function ($scope) {
    $scope.submitAreaInfo = function () {  
       if ($scope.fareainfo.$valid) {
         //after Form is Valid
       } else {
          $scope.fareainfo.$setSubmitted();
       }
    };
});
```

---

### Important Code Segments

1. **ng-app="areaApp" ng-controller="addCtrler"**
   Defines the angular app and controller
2. **ng-show="(fareainfo.$submitted || fareainfo.name.$dirty) && fareainfo.name.$error.required"** 
   Above condition ensure that whenever a user first sees the form there's no any validation error on the screen and after a user does changes to the form it ensure that validation message show on the screen. **.name.** is the name attribute of the input element.
3. **$scope.fareainfo.$valid**
   Above code, segment check whether the form is valid whenever a user submits the form.
4. **$scope.fareainfo.$setSubmitted();**
   Above code, segment ensures that all validation messages are displayed on the screen whenever a user submits the form without doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This worked for me.
<form  name="myForm" class="css-form" novalidate ng-submit="Save(myForm.$invalid)">
<input type="text" name="uName" ng-model="User.Name" required/>
<span ng-show="User.submitted && myForm.uName.$error.required">Name is required.</span>
<input ng-click="User.submitted=true" ng-disabled="User.submitted && tForm.$invalid" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
// in controller
$scope.Save(invalid)
{
if(invalid) return;
// save form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

G45,

I  faced same issue , i have created one directive , please check below hope it may be helpful

Directive :

```
    app.directive('formSubmitValidation', function () {

        return {
            require: 'form',
            compile: function (tElem, tAttr) {

                tElem.data('augmented', true);

                return function (scope, elem, attr, form) {
                    elem.on('submit', function ($event) {
                        scope.$broadcast('form:submit', form);

                        if (!form.$valid) {
                            $event.preventDefault();
                        }
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.submitted = true;
                        });


                    });
                }
            }
        };


  })
```

HTML :

```
<form  name="loginForm" class="c-form-login" action="" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate" form-submit-validation="">

<div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control c-square c-theme input-lg" placeholder="Email" ng-model="_username" name="_username" required>
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback c-font-grey"></span>
                                                <span ng-show="submitted || loginForm._username.$dirty && loginForm._username.$invalid">
                                                    <span ng-show="loginForm._username.$invalid" class="error">Please enter a valid email.</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
<button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-lg c-theme-btn c-btn-square c-btn-uppercase c-btn-bold">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this code:

```
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Save" onClick="validateTester()">
```

This funvtion will validate your result

```
function validateTester() {
    var flag = true
    var Tester = document.forms.Tester
    if (Tester.line1.value!="JavaScript") {
        alert("First box must say 'JavaScript'!")
        flag = false
        }
    if (Tester.line2.value!="Kit") {
        alert("Second box must say 'Kit'!")
        flag = false
        }
    if (flag) {
        alert("Form is valid! Submitting form...")
        document.forms.Tester.submit()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get your answer. What is Tester object? Is it something in AngularJS?. And I do not want to pop alerts. Just want to show hidden error messages. Thank you for answering