# Form validation in AngularJS not working as expected

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

I have an angular form. I am trying to implement some validation on required fields, like in [this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation) nice tutorial, which says that angular has this functionality "built in". However- it isn't working for me. When I submit the form without having filled out the fields, nothing happens. Can anyone see why?

```
    <form id = "myForm" name="myForm" novalidate>

                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.name.$invalid && !myForm.name.$pristine && submitted }">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="company.name" required>
                        <p ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid && !myForm.name.$pristine" >Your firm's name is required.</p>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.address.$invalid && !myForm.address.$pristine && submitted }">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id = "address" name="address"  ng-model="company.address" required>
                         <p ng-show="myForm.address.$invalid && !myForm.address.$pristine" class="help-block">Your address is required.</p>
                        </div>

<button type="submit" ng-click= "createAccount()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">GO

    </button>

        </form>
```

I have also included `$scope.submitted = true;` in my createAccount() function.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798375/show-validation-error-messages-on-submit-in-angularjs

Comment: @Chandermani this is similar to what I have attempted above- I have set the submitted property to true in the function in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that AngularJS is a client side framework. Your validation must be performed *before* you submit something.

Add `ng-disabled` to your submit button:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click= "createAccount()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">GO</button>
```

Or check the validation status in the `createAccount()` function like in the tutorial example you are referring to:

```
if (!$scope.myForm.$valid) {
   alert('Something is wrong');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one way of handling the validation- but in the tutorial, it shows it is possible to submit the form first and then have all the required fields highlighted with the error messages.

Comment: Ok, I think I grasped what you want. Besides the link @Chandermani posted, check also out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input