# AngularJS validation show validation msg on submit

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am dynamically adding fields and want "required" validation on each field I add.

Problem is angular validates these fields before i submit.

```
    <form name="outerForm">
                        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                            <data-ng-form name="innerForm">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="{{item.questionPlaceholder}}" name="fieldU" ng-model="item.question" required>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="innerForm.fieldU.$error.required">
                                    Required!
                                </span>
                                <input  type="text" name="userName" placeholder="enter text..." ng-model="item.text" required>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="innerForm.userName.$error.required">
                                    Required!
                                </span>
                            </data-ng-form>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" ng-click="save(items)" ng-disabled="outerForm.$invalid" />

                        <button ng-click="add()">New Field</button>
                    </form>
```

here is fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbw6ow8k/7/

I want required msg only to show when user did not add anything to text box and after he/she clicked submit

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798375/show-validation-error-messages-on-submit-in-angularjs

Comment: First of all, use the novalidate attribute on your form to prevent default browser validation behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd love to maintain one scope variable which will keep a track that form is submitted or not

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="outerForm" ng-init="submitted=false" novalidate="">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <data-ng-form name="innerForm">
                <input type="text" placeholder="{{item.questionPlaceholder}}" name="fieldU" ng-model="item.question" required/>
                <span class="error" ng-show="$parent.submitted&& innerForm.fieldU.$error.required">
                        Required!
                  </span>
                <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="enter text..." ng-model="item.text" required/>
                <span class="error" ng-show="$parent.submitted && innerForm.userName.$error.required">
                     Required!
                  </span>
            </data-ng-form>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="submitted=true;save(items)" ng-disabled="submitted && outerForm.$invalid" />
        <button ng-click="add()">New Field</button>
    </form>
    Items: {{items}}
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbw6ow8k/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `$scope.isSubmit` variable to detect whether the form has submitted or not:

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.save = function (question) {
        $scope.isSubmit = true; // Will be true if the form has submitted
        console.log(question)

    }
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.add = function () {
        if ($scope.items.length >= 10) {
            toastr.warning("Only 10 fields are allowed");
        } else {
            $scope.items.push({
                //inlineChecked: false,
                question: "",
                questionPlaceholder: "foo",
                text: ""
            });

        }
    };
});
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="outerForm" novalidate>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <data-ng-form name="innerForm">
                <input type="text" placeholder="{{item.questionPlaceholder}}" name="fieldU" ng-model="item.question" required> <span class="error" ng-show="innerForm.fieldU.$error.required && isSubmit">
                                        Required!
                                    </span>

                <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="enter text..." ng-model="item.text" required> <span class="error" ng-show="innerForm.userName.$error.required && isSubmit">
                                        Required!
                                    </span>

            </data-ng-form>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="save(items)" />
        <button ng-click="add()">New Field</button>
    </form>Items: {{items}}</div>
```

So, I deleted the `ng-disable` in the button in order to make the submit button clickable even though the form isn't correct. Moreover, you should add `novalidate` into the `form` tag to disable the default form validation from HTML5.

Here is the full source code on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbw6ow8k/8/).