# Date input field is giving required warning before submitting

Tags: jquery, angularjs, forms, date

I have used `angular-ui/ui-date` for date input and `angular-auto-validate` for form validation. Every other field like time for text is working fine but date input field is showing required message before submitting. I think issue maybe due inbuilt validation inside ui-date or maybe not.

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label>Start Date:</label>
    <input type="text" ui-date="{ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', minDate: 0}" ng-model="start_date" placeholder="Start Date" required="" />
</div>
```

Comment: No thats not an issue.

Comment: Just remove the attribute `required=""` if you don't want this.

Comment: I want the error, but I want it after clicking submit (same as for other fields)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18798375/863110

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `required=""` attribute, and replace it with `ng-required="false"`.

Read more: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date#ng-required-directive

Comment: Then it won't give error on  submitting (if empty).