# Input Validation in AngularJs Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-validation

Problem,

Somehow i can't get the validation right with AngularJs. I want just user input box to be red when required field is not present or wrong on submit.

I have create a Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/0ea77wRG3EJC13c22LLn. I have created a very simple Plunker, just to understand.

```
<input type="text" name="email"  ng-model="userEmail" required>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Go through this tutorial on [scotch.io](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation). It will give you an introduction to form validation.

and if you want validation messages will be displayed on click of submit button use a flag.
when you click on flag set the flag to true and use the conditions that were in angularJs like below

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitClicked && userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
```

and set the submitClicked flag to true on click of submit button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitClicked=true">Submit</button>
```

and you can even try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

Validation will not work if `novalidate` attribute is present in the form tag.

Remove it to work form validation on submit.