# Reset form after being submitted

Tags: angularjs

I know it has been asked several times and I already read the other questions but my problem still remains. I have a simple form and I want the validation to disappear after being successfully submitted.

Here is a plunker:

```
function FormController($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {
    firstname: 'Eugene',
    lastname: 'Crabs',
    username: 'MrCrabs'
  };
  $scope.submit = submit;

  function submit() {
    if ($scope.someForm.$invalid) {
      return;
    }
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.someForm.$setUntouched();
    return;
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/cJYStvlveHvAxhlza0Q0?p=preview

It's a simple task, it can't be that hard. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case change ng-show to

> (someForm.username.$dirty || submitted)

in code

```
<div class="error-message" ng-show="(someForm.username.$dirty || submitted)">
```

*note: it must be submitted, NOT form.$submitted*

update your function in controller

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    // set form is submitted
    $scope.submitted = true;

    if ($scope.someForm.$invalid) {
      return;
    }


    $scope.formData = {};

    // set form default state
    $scope.someForm.$setPristine();

    // set form is no submitted
    $scope.submitted = false;

    return;
  }
```

and it works

[more info about solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input)

[plukr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jRYH4SV2AiUabIvJ2twm?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting topic; I believe this forked plunker does what you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/RSSFFBmJ6MZtX3aaoNLb?p=preview

The key implementation points are:

1. Put an `enableMessages` flag in the scope
2. When the submit button is pressed, make the flag `true` *before* validation
3. Change the error message display conditions as:

   ```
   <span ng-show="someForm.firstname.$error.required && (someForm.firstname.$dirty || enableMessages)">Please enter your firstname</span>
   ```

   It reads "display this message if the field has an error and it has been touched by the user OR messages are enabled for the entire form".

   Putting such a long condition in the HTML is a bad practice, so I would consider writing a helper function, e.g. (UNTESTED CODE):

   ```
   $scope.showCondition = function(fieldName, validatorName) {
       return $scope.someForm[fieldName].$error[validatorName] &&
           ($scope.someForm[fieldName].$dirty || enableMessages);
   };
   ```

   The `ng-show` becomes much more concise:

   ```
   <span ng-show="showCondition('firstname', 'required')">Please enter your firstname</span>
   ```

   In this case the `enableMessages` is no longer a scope variable, but a private `var` of the controller.