# Angular validation after submit

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have form fields that are validated using required. The problem is, that the error is displayed immediately when the form is rendered. I want it only to be displayed after the user submit.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input).

but in my case, I have more than one buttom in the form, so I don't understand how to implement the ng-submit or a solution to my problem.

This is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NkYvUs4YCV0E4xEHkbsZ)
 of what I want to do.

HTML form:

```
  <form name="myForm">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="oldName">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button ng-click="copyName()"> Copy >> </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="newName" ng-model="newName" required>
        </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="oldEmail">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button ng-click="copyEmail()"> Copy >> </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" name="newEmail" ng-model="newEmail">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
    <button ng-click="Submit()">Submit </button>

  </form>
```

Comment: We are going to need to see some code of what you have already tried.  It's too hard to help without seeing what you already have.

Comment: The plunkr link is helpful, but the relevant code should be included directly in the post, as well.

Comment: yes, the html is only a preview of the plunker, the plunker has the code. The div that has the ng-show and says "invalid email" I need to show that only when click in the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put `$scope.myForm.$setSubmitted()` in your `$scope.submit` function which will set your form submitted. Now, in your error message's `ng-show`, you can have something like this:

```
<div ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.newEmail.$invalid">
  <strong>invalid email </strong>
</div>
```

[**working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wJR0uJJRftISldJISrfQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry I didn't understand well your solution, but the error summary, so the div shows Invalida email get triggered inmediatelly when while writting a wronge email without wait for the submit click.

Comment: @MarcosF8 do you have API call to make on submit?

Comment: no, I don't. When submit it will save the info in the Db doing and http call to my controller, so it goes to the MVC controller.

Comment: I am thinking in change the Copy buttons for links so I have only one submit buttons and try to use the Ng-submit.

Comment: @MarcosF8 so in success callback of http call, you can just have `$scope.myForm.$setPristine()` which will reset your form controller, and `myForm.$submitted` will no longer be true until you submit again.

Comment: I have update my plunker now is working exactly as I want, not sure if this like solution is something good? can you please check my plunker again ? https://plnkr.co/edit/NkYvUs4YCV0E4xEHkbsZ?p=preview   basically: on the submit button I am sending the boolean if the form is valid and setting an scope variable to show or hide my div. But then worked only for the first time: each time the user changed or remove a value the div showed automatically again, so I introduced the ng-keyup to change the boolean and now is fully working. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @MarcosF8 sure you can, one thing though, instead of passing `invalid` as param in submit, you can directly use `$scope.myForm.$invalid` in your `submit` function.