# Show error if button clicked and input text empty AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angular-ng-if

I create a login page , I show error if user click in input text and let him empty

but I need to show error if user don't click in input text and click login button

My code :

```
<form ng-submit="userForm.$valid && submit()" name="userForm" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.login.$touched && userForm.login.$invalid }">
      <input type="text" name="login"  placeholder="اسم المستخدم" class="form-control" ng-model="MainCtrl.login" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" required>
      <div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.login.$error" ng-if="userForm.login.$touched">
         <p ng-message="required">إسم المستخدم إجباري</p>
         <p ng-message="minlength">إسم المستخدم قصير</p>
         <p ng-message="maxlength">إسم المستخدم طويل</p>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.pass.$touched && userForm.pass.$invalid }">
      <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="كلمه السر" class="form-control" ng-model="MainCtrl.pass" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required>
      <div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.pass.$error" ng-if="userForm.pass.$touched">
         <p ng-message="required">كلمة السر اجبارية</p>
         <p ng-message="minlength">كلمة السر قصيرة</p>
         <p ng-message="maxlength">كلمة السر طويلة</p>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="log-btn">دخول</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

[this is my code in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iT4ZVUaFktE7Lso7SFYU?p=preview)

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i create a login formulair 

i have ng-messages if user click in input  text but not write aby thing the error show 

but if user d'ont write in input text and click button  submit no msg error showed in nedd to add a msg error if tow input text vide and button clicked 
please vist this link its my work : http://plnkr.co/edit/iT4ZVUaFktE7Lso7SFYU?p=preview

Comment: here is the  good reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us `required=""` on your input tag and `userForm.$submitted` on your error messages block:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (userForm.login.$touched && userForm.login.$invalid) ||  (userForm.$submitted && userForm.login.$invalid)}">
   <input type="text" name="login"  placeholder="اسم المستخدم" class="form-control" ng-model="MainCtrl.login" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" required="">
   <div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.login.$error" ng-show="userForm.$submitted || userForm.login.$touched">
      <p ng-show="userForm.login.$error.required" ng-message="required">required error</p>
      <p ng-show="userForm.login.$error.minlength">minLength error</p>
      <p ng-show="userForm.login.$error.maxlength">maxLength error</p>
   </div>
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wqZYwgH30fh3VvwfCk8r?p=preview)