# How to prevent form submit when clicking on button in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i am developing web application in angularjs. I have designed one form with some textboxes and multi select dropodwn. I used below link to put up multi select dropodwn.

```
http://embed.plnkr.co/xWvfWYjaW7TThKZONkv5/
```

Below is my multi select dropodwn.

```
<multiselect class="" multiple="true"
    ng-model="selectedCar"
    options="c.Location for c in locations"
    change="selected()" name="location" ng-required="true">
</multiselect>
```

Also i have some textboxes as below.

```
<div>
    <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form2.IDCopyNo.$dirty && form2.IDCopyNo.$invalid ">
    <span ng-show="form2.IDCopyNo.$invalid && form2.IDCopyNo.$dirty">* {{'Required' | translate}}</span>
    </span>
</div>
<input class="with-icon" type="text" name="IDCopyNo" ng-model="IDCopyNo" required my-maxlength="32">
```

Below is my full code.

```
<form name="form2" novalidate >
  <div class="inputblock" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((form2.$submitted && form2.location.$invalid)  || (form2.location.$invalid && form2.location.$dirty))}">
    <div>
      <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form2.location.$dirty">Select Location</span>
    </div>
    <multiselect class="" multiple="true" ng-model="selectedCar" options="c.Location for c in locations" change="selected()" name="location" ng-required="true">
    </multiselect>
  </div>
  <div class="inputblock" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((form2.$submitted && form2.IDCopyNo.$invalid )|| (form2.IDCopyNo.$invalid && form2.IDCopyNo.$dirty))}">
    <label class="inputblock-label" ng-show="user.IDCopyNo">{{ 'IDCopyNo' | translate }}</label>
    <div>
      <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form2.IDCopyNo.$dirty && form2.IDCopyNo.$invalid ">
       <span ng-show="form2.IDCopyNo.$invalid && form2.IDCopyNo.$dirty">* {{'Required' | translate}}</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <input class="with-icon" type="text" name="IDCopyNo" placeholder="{{ 'IDCopyNo' | translate }}" ng-model="IDCopyNo" required my-maxlength="32">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="{{ 'NEXT' | translate }}" class="blue-button" ng-click="saveDetail()">
</form>
```

Now the problem is whenever i do not enter value in my textbox and if i click on multi select dropodwn then my validation firing for textbox. Validation supposed to fire when i click on submit button. May i know how can i fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you add your full example? Hard to tell from the plunker provided...

Comment: Thank you. I have added full code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate form field only on submit or user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452247/validate-form-field-only-on-submit-or-user-input)

Comment: I'm not seeing it on [the example provided](http://embed.plnkr.co/xWvfWYjaW7TThKZONkv5/)...

Comment: Hi William. I changed as per Validate form field only on submit or user input  and no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jquery then you would use prevent default to achieve exactly what you are after:

```
jQuery("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

For angular As far as i am aware, the `ng-click` directive creates the `$event` variable which is available on the current scope. This can be referenced to a Java Script event which can then be used to call `stopPropagation`.

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
    Delete
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not using jquery. I am using Angularjs

Comment: In browser i saw below code. <button class="btn error" ng-click="toggleSelect()" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{'error': !valid()}">
    <span class="pull-left ng-binding">Select</span>
    <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
  </button>

Comment: There is already function on ng-click="toggleSelect()" so where should i write the code you provided?

Comment: Put it after toggleSelect() like the following: `<button class="btn error" ng-click="toggleSelect(); $event.stopPropagation();"`